# Let $W$ be well-ordered and $f$ increasing. If $z$ is the smallest $x$ such that $f(x)<x$, why does $f(f(z))<f(z)$?

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I am currently working on Set Theory of Thomas Jech, and I have a question about Lemma 2.4 which is :

Lemma 
If $(W, <)$ is a well-ordered set and $f:W \rightarrow W$ is an increasing function, then $f(x)\geq x$ for each $x \in W$.

Proof 
Assume that the set $X=\{x \in W : f(x) < x\}$ is nonempty and let $z$ be the least element of $X$. If $w=f(z)$, then $f(w)<w$, a contradiction.

I have a problem understanding the proof. I've found that the proof makes sense if $w \in X$ since

(i) $z\in X \rightarrow f(z)<z$ and 
(ii) $z$ is least element of $X \rightarrow (\forall x \in X)z \leq x)$ 
(iii) $f$ is increasing $\rightarrow (\forall x \in X)f(z) \leq f(x) $ 
(iv) $w \in X \rightarrow f(w) < w$
But by (iii) and $w \in X$, $f(z) \leq f(w) \iff w \leq f(w)$. This contradicts with (iv).

However, I can't figure out why $w \in X$. Why is it? Or is there any mistake with my proof?

Comment: $f(z) < z$ implies $f(f(z)) < f(z)$ since $f$ is increasing, hence $f(z) \in X$.

Comment: Ahhh thx,, I was stupid as hell. thank you.

Comment: Isn't the lemma false, or am I misunderstanding it? $\mathbb R$ is a well-ordered set, and $f(x)=\frac x2$ is increasing. But $\frac x2\leqslant x$.

Comment: @MrPie $\mathbb R$ is not well-ordered by the usual order.

Comment: @Tan what do you mean?

Comment: @MrPie I mean yes $\mathbb R$ can be well-ordered, but the usual order that we know does not well-order it. So if $<$ is the usual order we know, then $(\mathbb R, <)$ is not well-ordered so we cannot apply the lemma.

Comment: Out of topic, but I have a question: is there a reason to read Jech's thick book? It is well-written but not good at getting motivation of set-theoretic notions.

Comment: @HanulJeon My impression is that there is no serious alternative to Jech for the student aiming toward research in set theory. But I am not a set theorist, maybe that’s wrong.

Comment: @KevinArlin I agree with it to some degree (up to the first 5~6 chapters), but I found Kunen would be better for beginners because Jech does not explain the motivation of, e.g., club sets. Sometimes, Kunen is also not sufficient, so heavy googling and reading previous answers on MSE and MO is also necessary.

Comment: @HanulJeon Well, I was discussing necessity, not sufficiency :)

Answer (score 5):

Since $f$ is increasing and $w<z$, $f(w)<f(z)=w$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused with such a small thing lol